# How do I split a list so that it no longer has index values 0 or the end value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched for an awnser but what have come across is not what I need. I cant use this code:

```py
    def between(l1,low,high):
    
        l2 = []

        for i in l1:

            if(i > low and i < high):


                l2.append(i)

        return l2


    l = [1,3,4,5,1,4,2,7,6,5] 

    print( between(l,2,5) )
```

because my first index value changes every time I run the code. So does my ending index value. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: what do you want you code to do?

Comment: Your code shown has nothing to do with popping off the first value or removing last value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
f = lambda l: [i for i in l if i not in (l[0],l[-1])]
f(l)
```

```
[3, 4, 4, 2, 7, 6]
```

---

Without list comprehension:

```
def f(l):
    out = []
    for i in l:
        if i!=l[0] and i!=l[-1]:
            out.append(i)
    return out

f(l)
```

```
[3, 4, 4, 2, 7, 6]
```